# How to call a sub from a variable with the name of the sub?

Tags: string, raku, subroutine

Given the following code:

```
sub foo {
    say 'Hello';
}
my $call_me = 'foo';
```

How do I call the `sub foo` using `$call_me`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
::( "&" ~ $call_me )()
```

`::` accesses [the symbol table](https://rakudocs.github.io/language/packages#index-entry-::($c).m)  in the current package; subs are stored in that symbol table with the sigil `&` which is why we have to concatenate (`~`) the name with that to go from string to the function; that symbol table maps identifiers to the actual function.

For methods, this is easier:

```
my $method-name = "foo";
$object."$method-name"();
```

Note that you can create a name inside the `""` there, it doesn't have to be just a variable name.

Also note that the `()` are required in that case.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the explanation!

Comment: You'll have to thank @elizabeth-mattijsen too :-)

Comment: Great answer! I just note a couple of variations (i) ```my $c = '&foo'; ::(~$c)()``` embed the ```&``` in the name and uses str concat (~) as prefix to coerce $c to Str or (ii) ```my $d = 'foo''; ::("&$d")()``` use double quotes to interpolate the (&) onto the front.

Comment: You should use `&::($name)` instead of `::("&" ~ $name)`

Comment: @ugexe any reason? Is it just more idiomatic?

Comment: @jjmerelo it will at least save on a string-concat (creating a new short-lived temporary string) etc...